# find()ing outside of the document

Tags: jquery

I remember struggling with this before but I've googled and can't find the reference.  I want to:

```
var x = $('<div class="y">xxx</div>');
x.find('.y'); // returns 0 elements
```

and expect to find 1 element but find 0.  was it about being attached to the document? I tried it with similar failure:

```
var x = $('<div class="y">xxx</div>');
$(document).append(x);
alert($(document).find('.y').length); // also returns 0 elements
```

what gives?

Comment: can you post your html that you expect to get a returned element from.

Comment: Where are you trying to place? It won't have much effect outside of the document (and that doesn't work anyways, so...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var x = $('<div class="y">xxx</div>');
x.find('.y');
```

This doesn't work because what you're telling it to do is find an element with class `y` **within** the newly created element when the element itself is what you're looking for.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/wCb7H/embedded/js,result/) is something that works:

```
$('<div class="y">xxx</div>')
    .appendTo("html");

alert($('.y').length);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `x.find('.y')`, it is searching the children of `x` for objects with the class of `y`.  It does not search `x` itself.

If you did this, you would find it:

```
var x = $('<div><div class="y">xxx</div></div>');
x.find('.y');
```

You can see that work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bWxB4/.

Comment: oh Christ.  of course!  I need to have something like `$('<div><div class="y">xxx</div></div>')` in order for that to work...  somebody shoot me

Comment: Why did someone downvote this?  I wish a downvote required a reason/explanation.

Comment: Tried and failed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/allow-users-to-leave-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting

Comment: @Purmou - tried and failed what?  To leave a comment explaining why you downvoted?  There's no need for an anonymous comment if you're courteous.

Comment: I agree, I've often been downvoted without any way of knowing who or why.  I know the points aren't meaningful but I still resent it

Comment: @jfriend00: I meant to say that it's a suggestion that's failed on multiple occasions.

Comment: @Purmou - just because the suggestion has failed before doesn't mean I don't still think it's a good idea and doesn't mean that folks won't eventually see why it's a good idea.  I just think that downvotes should be educational.  If they're only penalizing with no idea why, then they don't really do anyone any good.  It's like if you send your kid on a timeout and don't tell them what they did wrong or what they should have done differently, the timeout only pisses them off and they don't learn anything.  It accomplishes nothing.  Similarly a downvote with no idea why accomplishes nothing.

Comment: @jfriend00: Um, yeah, I'm agreeing. I was just pointing out that the suggestion to possibly force (which is kind of not the way to go about it, but the best alternative) an anonymous comment has been deliberated several times to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) searches through the descendants of a jQueryified DOMElement. The element you have has no (DOMElement) descendants, the only descendant it has is a the text node with data `xxx`.

This will find one result:

```
var $x = $('<div><div class="y">xxx</div></div>');
$x.find('.y');
```

Since the div has a descendant with class `y`.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is because your searching "inside" the div, so the find() method doesn't find anything.

You could try:

```
var x = $('<div><div class="y">xxx</div></div>');
x.find('.y'); //1 element
```

The second one when you are appending to the document, and that doesn't really append anything in the dom, you could try

```
var x = $('<div class="y">xxx</div>');
$(document.body).append(x);
alert($(document).find('.y').length); //1
```